# How to send notfication in three days?

Tags: yii

How to write query to send notifications when user package expired after 3 days in Yii?

For example, account expired on `25th Dec`, then send expired email on `26th, 27th and 28th Dec`.

```
$expireddate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-3 days')); // (Coming from db)
$model = TblPackageUserplan::model()->findAll('expire_date>=:expire_date', array(':expire_date' => $expireddate));
```

It's not working correct, because its sending mail before `20th Dec`, too.
I want to send mail exactly user package expired after 3 days. How to get user details package expired after 3 days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use only criteria.

As of your question

> expired on 25th Dec, then send expired email on 26th, 27th and 28th Dec

You need to compare expire_date + 3days.

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
// With this condition we get only packages on next three days after expire_date.
$criteria->addCondition('DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE(),t.expire_date) BETWEEN 1 AND 3');
```